# What is the best way to implement parent-child in Elastic Search?

Tags: elasticsearch

I wonder how for example the questions and answers in Stack Overflow are mapped in Elastic Search.  You could implement answers as a child of questions, but in that case, how are then for example the lists rendered that give an overview of all answers that you have given ?

Such a list contains the question title, the number of answers and the date of your last answer. It is thus a mix of question data and answer data.

When using parent-child in Elastic Search, I can retrieve only data from questions OR from answers, but not from both.  So if I would like to create a view like Stack Overflow has, I would need to store the question title also in the answer.  But that then again gives overhead if the question title is changed.  In that case, both the question and all answers must be updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, checkout [nested type](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-nested-type.html) where you can store in index both question and answers and query them.

Here is example of index:

```
{
   "_index": "questions-development",
   "_type": "question",
   "_id": "8",
   "_score": 1,
   "_source": {
      "id": 8,
      "title": "Question title",               
      "answers": [
         {
            "answer_id": 42,                     
            "text": "Answer text"
         },
         {
            "answer_id": 88,                    
            "text": "Answer text"
         },
         {
            "answer_id": 79,                     
            "text": "Answer text"
         },
         {
            "answer_id": 80,                    
            "text": "Answer text"
         },
         {
            "answer_id": 8,                      
            "text": "Answer text"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: Thx. I will look into this.  I thought it was aeasier to use parent-child in case we add new answers, delete answers and modify answers.  These actions would in case of a nested type need to update partial data.

Comment: Have looked into this and the structure looks OK for searching. But how would you for example delete one of the answers or edit one of the answer texts ? Hope you can help.

Comment: @cyclomarc it depends on how are you implementing search, for example in Rails I specified callbacks and after changing nested attributes ES updates index.